# Regex for a third-person verb

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that matches a third person form of a verb created using the following rule:

> If the verb ends in e not preceded by i,o,s,x,z,ch,sh, add s.

So I'm looking for a regex matching a word consisting of some letters, then **not** i,o,s,x,z,ch,sh, and then "es". I tried this:

```
\b\w*[^iosxz(sh)(ch)]es\b
```

According to regex101 it matches "likes", "hates" etc. However, it does not match "bathes", why doesn't it?

Comment: `[^iosxz(sh)(ch)]` doesn't do what you think it does. It's equivalent to `[^chiosxz()]`.

Comment: *If the noun ends in e not preceded by i,o,s,x,z,ch,sh* - how about `house` , it comes to `houses`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - I meant to write "a verb in a third-person form". Sorry for the confusion. Moreover, this particular rule is meant to match only a small(ish) subset of all verbs.

Comment: How about using the negated class plus a lookbehind: [`\b\w*[^iosxz](?<![sc]h)es\b`](https://regex101.com/r/6TjHR9/1) (should be fine as long you require at least one preceding character).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\b(?=\w*(?<![iosxz])(?<![cs]h)es\b)\w*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/now8vH/1)

Since Python `re` does not support variable length alternatives in a lookbehind, you need to split the conditions into two lookbehinds here.

**Pattern details**:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `(?=\w*(?<![iosxz])(?<![cs]h)es\b)` - a positive lookahead requiring a sequence of:

  - `\w*`  - 0+ word chars
  - `(?<![iosxz])` - there must not be `i`, o`, s`, `x`, `z` chars right before the current location and...
  - `(?<![cs]h)` - no `ch` or `sh` right before the current location...
  - `es` - followed with `es`...
  - `\b` - at the end of the word
- `\w*` - zero or more  (maybe `+` is better here to match 1 or more) word chars.

See [Python demo](http://ideone.com/5KAmVf):

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'\b(?=\w*(?<![iosxz])(?<![cs]h)es\b)\w*')
s = 'it matches "likes", "hates" etc. However, it does not match "bathes", why doesn\'t it?'
print(re.findall(r, s))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match strings that end with `e` and are not preceded by `i`,`o`,`s`,`x`,`z`,`ch`,`sh`, you should use:

```
(?<!i|o|s|x|z|ch|sh)e
```

Your regex `[^iosxz(sh)(ch)]` consists of [character  group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), the `^` simply negates, and the rest will be *exactly* matched, so it's equivalent to:

```
[^io)sxz(c]
```

which actually means: "match anything that's not one of "io)sxz(c".

Comment: Your [`(?<!i|o|s|x|z|ch|sh)e` regex does not compile](http://ideone.com/tYGFb0) in Python.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I wrote a pure regex, regardless of the programming language.

Comment: There is no such a thing as a "pure" regex. Your `(?<!i|o|s|x|z|ch|sh)e` will work in .NET, Java, PCRE, but not in Python `re`.